# Limit the multiplied amount result to 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, html, decimal, limit, tofixed

I made a simple javascript that multiplies an amount and shows the result. However, I want to limit the result to 2 decimals. I've tried using toFixed, but that doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

```js
function MultiplyTheAmount() {
 var multiplier = 0.75;
 var roundedMultiplier = multiplier.toFixed(2);
 document.getElementById('multiplyResult').innerHTML = document.getElementById('multiplyAmount').innerHTML * roundedMultiplier;
};
MultiplyTheAmount();
```

```html
<ul style="list-style:none;">
  <li>Amount:</li>
  <li id="multiplyAmount">119.99</li>
  <li><br/></li>
  <li>Multiply by:</li>
  <li>0.75</li>
  <li><br/></li>
  <li>Result:</li>
  <li id="multiplyResult"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the  `toFixed` method to the end result to eliminate the magnified [floating point inaccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) you are seeing:

```js
function MultiplyTheAmount() {
    var multiplier = 0.75;
    var roundedMultiplier = multiplier.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('multiplyResult').textContent = ( 
        +document.getElementById('multiplyAmount').textContent * roundedMultiplier
    ).toFixed(2);
};
MultiplyTheAmount();
```

```html
<ul style="list-style:none;">
  <li>Amount:</li>
  <li id="multiplyAmount">119.99</li>
  <li><br/></li>
  <li>Multiply by:</li>
  <li>0.75</li>
  <li><br/></li>
  <li>Result:</li>
  <li id="multiplyResult"></li>
</ul>
```

Not related to the question, but I would suggesting the use of `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when not dealing with `HTML` content.

Comment: And it should also be suggested to store `document.getElementById('multiplyResult')` in a variable to avoid accessing it twice.

Comment: @andlrc, that element is accessed only once. The other reference is to `multiplyAmount`, not `multiplyResult`.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer @trincot, your solution works :) I'm also using textContent now instead of innerHTML.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for clarifying :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to limit the final result to have 2 decimal places:

```
(document.getElementById('multiplyAmount').innerHTML * roundedMultiplier).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I had toFixed in the wrong place, this is much better, thanks! :)